# Type mismatch for generic class method call

Tags: scala

Please consider the following trivial example:

```
class C[P](val list: Seq[P]){
  def print(e: P){
    println(e)
  }
}

object Test{
  def g[P](c: C[P]) = {
    c.print(c.list(0))
  }

  def f(i: Int): C[_] = {
    i match {
      case 1 => new C(Seq(1, 2, 3))
      case _ => new C(Seq("A", "B", "C"))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c = f(1)
    g(c) // works
    c.print(c.list(0)) // does not work
  }
}
```

My question is, in the main function, why the first call compiles, but the second gives "type mismatch" error.

Is there any other (better) way to do what is intended here?

**Edit 1**:

According to the answer by @chengpohi, I can change the type of the returned value of `f` to `C[Any]`, but this generally may not work. For example, if we change the code to

```
class B[P]

class BInt extends B[Int]

class BString extends B[String]

class C[P](val list: Seq[P], val obj: B[P]) {
  def print(e: P) {
    println(e)
  }
}

object Test {
  def g[P](c: C[P]) = {
    c.print(c.list(0))
  }

  def f(i: Int): C[_] = {
    i match {
      case 1 => new C(Seq(1), new BInt)
      case _ => new C(Seq("String"), new BString)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c = f(1)
    g(c) // works
    c.print(c.list(0)) // does not work
  }
}
```

I cannot change the return type of `f` to `C[Any]` anymore ("type mismatch").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def f(i: Int): C[Any] = {
    i match {
      case 1 => new C(Seq(1, 2, 3))
      case _ => new C(Seq("A", "B", "C"))
    }
  }
```

Try to set the `f` method return type: `C[Any]` from `C[_]`, for type`C[_]`, the compiler will translate `C[_]` to `C<?>`.

for:

```
  def g[P](c: C[P]) = {
    c.print(c.list(0))
  }
```

this method works, this is caused by that we have bound `P` type in this method `g`, so the compiler can infer this generic `P` (`Object` type).

but in main method:

```
c.print(c.list(0))
```

There is no type context for c, and c's type is `C[_]`, but `c.list`'s type is `Seq[Any]`, and for the Generic Type `P` in the `c.print` will be thought as `_$1` type. so the `type mismatch` compile error throwed.

Comment: IMO, this is more of a workaround and cannot be applied to more general cases, because `C[_]` should mean `C[A for some type A]`, which is not equivalent to `C[Any]`. Please see my updated post for a more general example.

Comment: @MathFun for your edit, you can try to cast it to `C[Any]`, like:    `val res = i match {
      case 1 => new C(Seq(1), new BInt)
      case _ => new C(Seq("String"), new BString)
    }

    res.asInstanceOf[C[Any]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use type variable patterns to give a name to the type parameter:

```
f(1) match {
  case c: C[a] => c.print(c.list(0))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think this is similar to the `g` function in the original post.